# Running Cmake via WSL Remote

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using cmake, mostly on windows.
I wanted to test compiling on linux and for that I wanted to use WSL.

I correctly (i think) setup the CMake Tools extension for Remote: WSL, cmake is installed on wsl, too.

The `settings.json` of the cmake extension for WSL (`Remote: WSL`) looks like this:

```
"cmake.configureArgs": [
    "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-linux",
    "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/raildex/downloads/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
],
"cmake.cmakePath": "/home/raildex/downloads/cmake/bin/cmake"
```

The `settings.json` of the cmake extension for Windows (`Workspace`) looks like this:

```
"cmake.configureArgs": [
  "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\\Dokumente\\Repositories\\vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake",
  "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x86-windows"
]
```

When I use the command `CMake: Configure` within a WSL remote connection, it looks for the toolchain file on my Windows directory:

> [proc] Executing command: /home/raildex/downloads/cmake/bin/cmake
> --no-warn-unused-cli **-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Dokumente\Repositories\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake** **-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x86-windows** -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++ -S/mnt/d/Dokumente/Repositories/Project -B/mnt/d/Dokumente/Repositories/Project/build -G Ninja

It runs cmake from WSL, but the configuration is for Windows?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the settings of the workspace override the settings of the remote connection.

The order of overriding is User < Remote < Workspace

My (temporary) solution is to set the cmake options for **Windows** in the User Settings and keep the Workspace Settings empty.